# Can someone help me to recover my stuck bnb into a contract adress

Tags: etherscan, bsc, bscscan

\accidentally sent my bnb to a coin address transaction hash
Oxle440d1811c60ee3c5dbacea50bf9fac2e3c2
e5ce0c02c73fe08c55682825348
instead of sending to my wallet I sent to coin address I checked my bnb still there in your account please can you help me recover I'm not an expert in this but that money is everything to me
I'm not a scammer i just lost my fund and i just need a help. Check link https://bscscan.com/address/0x5e27e384acbba20982f991893b9970aaf3f43181

Comment: wdym? the transaction is 105 days old.

Comment: Yes and I'm looking for help since that day

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think it's possible to recover your BNB, but you need the help from the deployer of Tyrion finance.

You sent BNB to this address on bsc: 0x5e27e384aCBBa20982f991893B9970AaF3f43181. This is an empty address on bsc, but it's actually a smart contract on ethereum.

The deployer (creator) of this contract can deploy a contract to the same address on bsc. This is because the address of the deployed contract depends only on the *deployer* and its *nonce*. This is why you can't do it yourself.

The contract on ethereum was deployed by 0x798F580905cE3F751800c7e9cDe3D1712a182e49 with nonce `0`. You're lucky that on bsc he hasn't sent transactions yet, so he still has `0` nonce there.

So try contacting him/her. Show him this answer. What he needs to do is deploy a simple contract like this in its first transaction (no other transactions before the deployement!):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Recover {
    // this should be your address
    address constant recipient = 0xAA65dd8A436bea7c8adA7eC443878f57a2152Cae;

    constructor() {
        payable(recipient).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok we have a problem, Infura which I use with my tools doesn't support BSC so I can't do it today. It will take a longer time and I may have to charge you for it because I have to pay my developer. He risoonce me this

Comment: He can use a free RPC from here https://chainlist.org/. He can can charge you a little for his time spent, it's between you and him to discuss. Just don't give him money immediately, but tell him to keep a % out of the money recovered.

Comment: They don't want to help me there is anything i can do? Pleas help me

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing else you can do